# Como alterar banco de dados já em uso, com dados dentro?

Tags: phpmyadmin

tenho um banco da dados com dados dentro.
Preciso alterar a colletion de um determinado dado de uma tabela do banco.
Como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O motivo é que não estou conseguindo cadastrar contas com acentuação.

Esse é o erro que aparece no console quando tento salvar um dado com acento.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não sou a melhor pessoa pra responder, mas acredito que não tenha solução. Você pode alterar o collation e os novos dados passarão a vir com acentos, no entanto, os antigos provavelmente continuarão "bugados" e você teria que fazer um update em todos os dados antigos pra adequá-los.

Comment: Se exportar os dados do banco, recriá-lo com a *collation* correta e importá-los novamente não funciona?

Comment: É que criei a estrutura todo no Workbench, fiz a ligação entre as tabelas e não consigo fazer as alterações no phpMyAdmin, ele não permite.